# Python list of lists not retaining information, which is once stored successfully

Tags: python

I have a file I am reading which goes like this :

```
/m/09c7w0
9.15810037736e+12   3957219322.11
9085777777.78   2585810931.38
10000000000.0   0.0
3.6e+16     0.0
4.65962485769e+12   8.39090575309e+11
0.540909090909  0.25489586271
3.99875996113   2.79866987366
41.3330962083   29.8486587064
10000000000.0   0.0
2341215333.91   88390569.3568
/m/09c7w0
9.15810037736e+12   3957219322.11
9085777777.78   2585810931.38
10000000000.0   0.0
3.6e+16     0.0
4.65962485769e+12   8.39090575309e+11
0.540909090909  0.25489586271
3.99875996113   2.79866987366
41.3330962083   29.8486587064
10000000000.0   0.0
2341215333.91   88390569.3568
```

Now I am reading this file and storing it in a list of lists. Below is the Python code. In the `elif` portion, `float(temp[0])` transfers the correct values to the `country_catgs_stats[c][2*v]` and so does `float(temp[1][:-1])` transfer the correct values to the `country_catgs_stats[c][2*v+1]` and hence prints everything alright.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

country_stats = open("country_stats")
lines_all = country_stats.readlines()

temp = [0.0] * 22
country_catgs_stats = [temp] * 241

c = 0
v = 0
c_inc = False
for line in lines_all:
  temp = line.split('\t')
  if len(temp) == 1 and c_inc == True:
    c_inc = False
    c += 1
  elif len(temp) == 2:
    if c_inc == False:
      c_inc = True
      v = 0
    country_catgs_stats[c][2*v] = float(temp[0])
    country_catgs_stats[c][2*v+1] = float(temp[1][:-1])
    print c, '\t', 2*v, '\t', float(temp[0]), country_catgs_stats[c][2*v], '\t', 2*v+1, '\t', float(temp[1][:-1]), country_catgs_stats[c][2*v+1]
    v += 1

for i in range(0, 240):
  for j in range(0, 10):
    print country_catgs_stats[i][2*j], '\t', country_catgs_stats[i][2*j+1]
```

But once out of the `1st` `for` loop, when I am printing the list of lists `country_catgs_stats[c]` second time, it prints nothing - everything is printed as :

```
0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
...
0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
```

I am running against time for a submission and this problem is driving me bonkers for the last 3.5 hours. I'm taking a refuge here. Someone please help.

PS. Is the definition for `country_catgs_stats` also correct - or is there an error lurking there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition for country_catgs_stats is not correct. Try the same thing with smaller numbers:

```
>>> temp = [0.0] * 5
>>> country_catgs_stats = [temp] * 5
>>> country_catgs_stats
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

So far so good. Let me set a single thing in temp:

```
>>> temp[0]=9
>>> country_catgs_stats
[[9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
>>>
```

Same effect if the assignment is into country_catgs_stats:

```
>>> country_catgs_stats[0][1] = 8
>>> country_catgs_stats
[[9, 8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [9, 8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [9, 8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [9, 8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [9, 8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
>>>
```

See how every list has changed. There aren't five lists, but one list referenced five times. Or in your code, the same list linked 241 times.

It works as it runs, because you assign and print immediately, before overwriting it the next time through the loop.

Try

```
country_catgs_stats = []
for i in range(241):
    country_catgs_stats.append([0.0] * 22)
```

Comment: Quite precisely caught it, you. I had thought I would be able to understand the mistake on my own, but didn't know how to `test` a simple scenario of my definition.

Comment: You could even use a list comprehension : `country_catgs_stats = [ temp[:] for i in range(241) ]`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Is it not so, that keeping `temp` inside the list definition of `country_catgs_stats` would cause me the same problem of the same simultaneous updates in all the sublists of `country_catgs_stats` ?

Comment: @SunilKundal : No I first made a similar mistake as yours (in my own post below) but glglgl warned me and I fixed it. I've now tested it : it is correct ...

Comment: @SunilKundal There is a difference between ``[temp for i in range(n)]`` and ``[temp[:] for i in range(n)]``.

Comment: I'll follow back on this question in a couple of hours. Thank you guys for the quick help !

Answer (score 0):

How vicious (*) !

You tried to solve the problem of reusing the inner list in a list of list by preallocating the list of list (`country_catgs_stats`). But the way you did is even worse, because is is 241 time **the same inner `temp` list** !

Hopefully it should be easy to fix by simply writing :

```
country_catgs_stats = [ temp[:] for i in range(241) ]
```

because now you get 241 **copies** of temp ...

(*) not you of course, but the mistake :-)

Comment: No. Now, you make a copy of `temp` and use this copy 241 times... See: `a=[]; b=[a[:]] * 10; b[1] is b[2]; b[1] is a` will give you `True` and then `False`.